# What to do with a method that can be used in many classes?

Tags: php, oop

This may be a dumb question but i'll give it a go anyway.

This is for PHP5. Lets say i have two classes `Member.class.php` and `Forum.class.php` and have a [method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#100456) called `returnDate($queryDate)` that can be used in the two classes - for the member class it returns users last seen date and for the forum class it returns last answered. For example, `Member: Jonny - last seen **2 mins ago**.` `Forum post: last answered **10 mins ago**.`

Im assuming it's a bad idea to put this method into the two classes to avoid duplication so im wondering is this where an interface class would come in handy? Or do I do something obvious like create a class for the site to put it in e.g. `Website.class.php`. Just trying to further my understanding thanks.

Comment: This is somewhat subjective. I don't think it's bad to put the method in two separate classes, as it is likely they do substantially different work to collect the information. If you want to centralize something you could make a String.class.php that has static methods to translate the returned value in to a localized string (dynamically making it say "2 minutes ago" or "3 hours ago" based on centralized rules).

Comment: @dpk: The answer box is a little lower :P

Comment: Yeah. I didn't answer it as I don't think it really has a "right" answer. I could go in to all of the other options, like subclassing both from one common class or writing an interface (as he talks about) but it's really all dependent on the environment. (Also, I meant to add a little more to my comment but Stackoverflow.com mistakenly traps "return" while entering text in these textarea boxes. So I just gave up and left it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two functions are essentially identical...

My suggestion: Composition > Inheritance.

Create a 'DateHelper' class, and make an instantiation of it a component of each of those classes. That way you've got once place for the code to live (DRY!) and it's clear that there's some shared functionality between the two classes.

You could also make the method static, and call DateHelper::returnDate($x), but I try to minimise use of static functions where I can.

This approach has the advantage of letting you add more date-related functionality, and keeping it in a single place that is comprehensible as being about date-related stuff.